# Continue repeating function even if an error occur

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a script which scraping a website every 7 secs and send wp message if statement true. But if any error occur while scraping, script stops. How can I run the code even so any error occur in the script?

```
import mysql
import mysql.connector
from twilio.rest import Client
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sched
import time

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

account_sid = "xxx"
account_token = "xxx"

client = Client(account_sid, account_token)

from_whatsapp_number = "whatsapp:xxx"
to_ali = "whatsapp:xxx"
number = "+xxx"
to_me = "whatsapp:xxx"


tolist = [to_me,to_ali]
# , to_ali, to_yiho, to_eno, to_huso,to_ramo, to_yuno, tohuso1, tohuso2, tohuso3, tohuso4

url = "https://sports2.holiganbet{}.com/tr/spor/yuksek-oran/101/dunya/240/lokasyon".format(
    659)


def fetch_data(sc):

    URLtest = url
    req = requests.get(URLtest)
    soupi = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
    container = soupi.find('a', attrs={'class': 'Anchor NavList__Anchor'})
    if not container:
        print("No match")
    elif container:
        time.sleep(2)

        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            password="",
            database="holi",)
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()

        URL = url
        r = requests.get(URL)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        # liste_elemanlari = soup.find_all('li', attrs={'class': 'NavList__Item'})
        liste_elemanlari = soup.find('ul', attrs={'class': 'NavList'})

        linkelementleri = liste_elemanlari.find_all(
            'a', attrs={'class': 'Anchor NavList__Anchor'}, href=True)

        for link_element in linkelementleri:
            unique_id = link_element['href'].split("/")[-1]

            macadi = link_element.text

            mycursor.execute(
                "SELECT macadi, COUNT(*) FROM maclar WHERE macadi = %s  and title = %s GROUP BY macadi", (macadi, macadi))

            myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
            # gets the number of rows affected by the command executed
            row_count = mycursor.rowcount

            if row_count == 0:
                for person in tolist:
                    client.messages.create(
                        body=link_element,
                        from_=from_whatsapp_number,
                        to=person
                    )
                    time.sleep(1)

                sql = "INSERT INTO maclar (id, macadi,title) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
                val = (unique_id, macadi, macadi)
                mycursor.execute(sql, val)
                mydb.commit()
            if row_count > 0:
                print("Maç Mevcut Mesaj Yok")
                time.sleep(1)
    sc.enter(10, 1, fetch_data, (sc,))


s.enter(10, 1, fetch_data, (s,))
s.run()
```

Comment: Do you know about catching exceptions In Python?

Comment: yeap i try that too; try : #code except: pass which i did but it still stops

Comment: "tried that too". Since it's the natural thing to do, you should indicate what failed, what the problem was with catching any exceptions inside the loop.

Comment: fixed because i used try except block on the wrong place

Answer (score 0):

Add a try catch block and end error gracefully without rethrowing the error

Comment: yeap i try that too; try : #code except: pass which i did but it still stops

Answer (score 0):

Exception handling

```
try :
#yourlogic
except Exception as e:
sleep(2) or pass
```